# Which is the More appropriate JFree Dataset to Pass 3 Strings and 1Double Values as Parameter?

Tags: dataset, jfreechart

Which is more appropriate: JFree Dataset to pass 3 Strings or 1 Double value as a parameter?

```
**SALES_TERRITORY**  **Attribute_Desc**  **TRANS_TYPE**    **BOOK_NET**

     ASIA                 1-Tier            POS              678976
     ASIA                 2-Tier            ADJ                8966
```

I need to pass these values from database table columns to a dataset `(3 Strings,1 Double value)` . Which dataset is appropriate to use?

Earlier i was using CategoryDataset for `(2 Strings , 1 Double value)`.

### Is there any dataset available to pass the above values to a single dataset?

tried with JDBCCategoryDataset.If my database result in 4 (Above Table)columns.How can i do some operation on the returned results?

i can do simply with 2 Strings and associated value using

DefaultCategoryDataset.setValue(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3)); and have used getvalue method to retrieve the value

Which dataset is exact for passing four column values from db resultset(Above Table Results).?

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows waht you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

`ChartFactory.createBarChart()` with a `CategoryDataset` seems apropos; [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.62) is an example. With that much dynamic range, I'd look at substituting a `LogAxis` for the range.

Addendum: *Could you please let me know the exact implementation class for the category dataset?*

As you are accessing a database, [`JDBCCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html) may be worth a look.

Comment: Could you please let me know the exact implementation class for the category data-set to pass 3 Strings and 1 double value associated with it.

Comment: I'd start with the bar chart demo cited and then try the JDBC variation mentioned above.